# Related Box Padding

Tags: bug, design

[image]

There's broken padding/margin on the bottom of the related box, Chrome 26 on OS X Mountain Lion

Comment: Confirmed in Opera 12.11.

Comment: Confirmed in _Chrome 26.0.1410.43 m_ on Win(7) when there're three lines.

Comment: confirmed on `FF 19.0.2` We need a `clear:both`

Answer (score 2):

I saw that this happens in other sites of the network and opened a ticket at the main Meta: [Network wide padding issues in the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179110/185667).

Forwarding the answer that just been posted by one of the developers:

> This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2013.5.20.1020.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed for *Firefox 20.0* and *Internet Explorer 9.0.14*.

A `clear: both;` wouldn't do, though.

I'd vote for:

```
.module {
    ... other properties ...
    padding: 0 10px 10px; // before: 0 10px 15px
}

.module .spacer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px; // before: 8px
}

.show-votes .sidebar-linked a,
.show-votes .sidebar-related a {
    ... other properties ...
    margin-bottom: 0; // before: 10px
}
```

That should do the trick.